# Is Play serving cached page content, when the back button is hit?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

In one of my Play-based applications, there is a button, which changes its text from "Follow" to "Unfollow", when clicked, after a successful call to the server.

I spotted that if I go to another page, and then click the back button, the text of the button flipped back to what used to be before the click, although the data was successfully stored on the server, and I used a JavaScript success handler to change the text.

If I refresh the page completely, I see that the page is rendered correctly, i.e. the buttons have the proper states.

This brings me to the conclusion that Play might be doing some page caching to handle the back button click. Is this correct? How can I disable that? Can I do it for that particular page only?

Answer (score 2):

> This brings me to the conclusion that Play might be doing some page caching to handle the back button click. Is this correct?

No, your browser do that, not Play.

This is normal and expected behavior for all browsers: the "back" page is displayed from cache, the server is not called at all (Unless there are dynamic event -ajax-, obviously).